# C# Define Variables using Loop

Tags: c#

Ok this might be a weird question and I don't really know how to phrase it so I just show you an example:

```
int i = 0; 
int k = 100;    
while (i <5) {     
    ***response+i*** = k + i;    
    i++;    
}
```

I want to declare multiple Variables (response1, response2, respons3 ...) using a loop, so that in the end the result is:

```
response1 = 101
response2 = 102
response3 = 103
```

etc.

I am still a beginner at C# and programming in general, so I don't know if that is even possible how I imagine it, hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: Have you learnt about arrays yet?

Answer (score 1):

First, You can not define a variable by using two variable. That is not how compiler work.
Maybe you should try to create a `Array` or `List` to store the value

like this example

```
int i = 0;

int k = 100;

int[] response = new int[100];

while (i < 5)
{
    response[i] = k + i;
    i++

}
```

if you don't know the array size you want , try to do with `List`

```
List<int> response = new List<int>();
int i = 0;
int k = 100;
while (i < 5)
{
    response.Add(i + k);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: I want to supply some additional information about your question, C# is strongly typed so you can't create variables dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You should really use an array for these values, it's not really possible to use dynamic variable names.

I would also use a for loop where you need the index variable rather than having to manually update it in the while loop.

```
var results = int[5];
int k = 100;

for (var i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
  results[i] = k + i;
```

Comment: Good idea, last thing we need is an IndexOutOfRangeException.